# why there is no /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh

Tags: 16.04, xorg, systemd

I would like to use `systemd --user` to run xautolock. For that I would need `DISPLAY` variable set in the environment. Normally, systemd provides a script for setting necessary environment, however it is missing in Ubuntu 16.04.
Any ideas where to get this script or replacements?

Answer (score 1):

The script is available in the systemd source, found on [Github](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v229/xorg/50-systemd-user.sh)
(link goes to systemd version 229, which is installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS install)